# when we assign one struct pointer to other pointer, why can't we use the assigned pointer directly to access the data?

Tags: c++

I have done something like this.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}
node *n1 = n;
```

when i am trying to access n1->data it is telling access violated.

Comment: plz post usage relevant code

Comment: Post the actual code, this wouldn't compile. But you probably don't have the n ptr properly allocated.

Comment: access violation usually means that you are working with invalid pointers.  Step through the code with a debugger to find out what went wrong.

Comment: `node *n1 = n;` is fine. There must be a problem with `n`. Post a complete program that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). The code is probably caused by the undefined behavior that is generated when dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Given your:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}
```

if you declare:

```
node *n;
node *n1 = n;
```

both `n->data` and `n1->data` cause UB.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reason for this behavior. Some of them are

1. The original pointer from which you are assigning is not initialized properly.

   `node* n1;
   node* n2;
   cout<<n1->data; //UB
   cout<<n2->data; //UB`
2. After assignment, the original object goes out of scope.

   `void func(node* n)
   {
     node temp;
     n= & temp;
   }`

   `int main(){
     node* n;
     func(n);
     cout<< n->data; \\UB
   }`